# powermock +mockito mock private method with more than on param

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I want to mock a private method with two parameters in my bean named TestBean,
below is my program:

```
Student student = mock(Student.class);
    Teacher teacher = mock(Teacher.class);
    doReturn("mockResult").when(testBean1, method(TestBean.class, "kk", Student.class, Teacher.class)).withArguments(student,teacher);
```

kk is the method name,it need two parameter:first is student ,second teacher.
I got t error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.DefaultPrivatelyExpectedArguments.withArguments(DefaultPrivatelyExpectedArguments.java:36)
```

but when i change my method:remove the second method,it works,below is the program:

```
Student student = mock(Student.class);
    doReturn("mockResult").when(testBean1, method(TestBean.class, "kk", Student.class)).withArguments(student);
```

i want know why ?

Comment: Could you post the method signature(s) from TestBean?

Comment: this seems correct. Did the issue get resolved